# Deploying chrome extensions that are not in chrome webstore

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, browser, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I found that the chrome webbrowser recently disabled the ability to deploy extensions that are not from the [chrome webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/home). I tried opening my extension.crx directly intro chrome and it wont work anymore, it just download the file.

I know I could use the "load unpacked extension", but I need to do it in about 50 computers, so it's not a very practical way.

Does anyone knows any other ways to deploy an extension that is not in the webstore?

Maybe "loading an unpacked extension" programmatically from an .exe or something like that.

Comment: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/external_extensions.html

Comment: I've end up using something similtar. Created a key on the registry and path & version values, then when starting chrome the extensions gets installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried dragging it over to Chrome, either from the download bar or the file browser on your operating system? I seem to remember this has been an issue earlier...

Comment: As I said, i need to install it on >50 computers, I don't want to do that drag & drop manually (which is a valid working method). Also the drag & drop method only works if dragging into the chrome://chrome/extensions/ tab.

Answer (score -1):

There is more information about how to complete this on the Chrome Dev site:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/crx

It looks as if you need to create a zip file, then add additional headers to the beginning of that file, then change the file extension from ".zip" to ".crx"

If serving this file from a web-server, you should use the header "application/x-chrome-extension" to make the Chrome browser understand this is an installable theme/app/extension.